# mongodb in docker ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: mongodb, docker

Please help me with this. I tried the following steps, but I am not able to connect to MongoDB.

1. RUN: `docker run -p 27017:27017 --name my-mongo -d mongo:latest`
2. RUN: `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' my-mongo`
3. The output of the above command is an IP-Address. Let the IP-Address is `172.17.0.2`.
4. Open in browser this link: http://172.17.0.2:27017/
5. If the following output is displayed in a browser then everything is fine: `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.` I am stuck here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP Address you are trying to access is the container's private ip that is only accessible from within the docker network.

Using the parameter `-p` that you're specifying on the `docker run` you're telling docker to map a local port on your host to the port specified on the container, in this case `local port 27017` to `container port 27017` and after that you can access it with `localhost`: `http://localhost:27017`

Read more about this here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/